# php - PDO prepare bindParam with dash not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have French cities in a database like this:

```
01001   Abergement-Clémenciat
01002   Abergement-de-Varey
01004   Ambérieu-en-Bugey
01005   Ambérieux-en-Dombes
01006   Ambléon
01007   Ambronay
01008   Ambutrix
01009   Andert-et-Condon
01010   Anglefort
```

And I have a PDO prepare query:

```
$sth = $this->connection->prepare('
        SELECT code
        FROM insee
        WHERE city = :city
    ');
$sth->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch();
```

When city is equal to "Ambronay" or "Ambléon" or "Ambutrix", fetch is returning something.
But when city is equal to "Abergement-de-Varey" or "Saint-Étienne" or something else with dash (-), fetch is returning nothing while the data is in database.

What could be the reason?

Thank you per advance.

Comment: try escaping dash: `$city = preg_replace("/\-/", '\-', $city);`

Comment: Thank you but the result is the same. The fetch is returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an encoding problem. At this Point you should force php to use multibyte strings for `$city`. If the problem still exits, check your database encoding, which should be for stings like that utf8. If the problem now still exists, check your driver connection encoding. Note that this setting is very database dependend. E. g. in MySQL you could define a different character set for each table, where this is impossible in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @alpham8.

I forgot to put the encoding when calling PDO, it works now.

So the solution is :

```
$this->connection = new PDO($dns, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```